# In laravel 5.4 php artisan migrate creating only one table

Tags: laravel-5.4

I created three migrations with php artisan make:migration and after that I ran php artisan migrate. This command creating only one table in my database instead of 3.

Comment: Please provide source code of your migrations. And specify wich migration was successfully migrated. Just more specifics.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I solve the problem. I just follow these steps:https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error